# First command in a bash pipe runs is able to modify parent process variable? Why?

Tags: linux, unix, pipe

- I am using bash version 4.3.4
- I know that generally, builtin commands should not get forked ( The shell executes the command directly, without invoking another program.)

While randomly playing with pipes I saw the following thing that I  do not understand:

a) If I set a shell variable as: a=1 and then run:  a=2 | a=3; echo $a | echo $a --> I will get a=1 (nothing modified)

b) While a=1 as nothing was modified with the previously command, I then try to run: a=2; echo $a | a=3; echo $a | echo $a that will give me a=2 in the echo reply on the stoud and even in a normal "echo $a" after.

I can try to put "a=x" with another value for a in any other place in the pipe, like in "a)", but variable "a" will remain unchanged.
Why that "echo $a" in the first portion of the pipe modified the "a" variable in the parent shell?

Comment: If you run `a=2; echo $a | a=3`, then the first command (`a=2`) is not in the pipeline.  It is executed in the shell that is executing the pipeline.  So of course it changes `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting of the question makes it hard to be sure what is confusing you, but note that:

```
a=2; echo $a | a=3; echo $a | echo $a
```

is exactly the same as:

```
a=2
echo $a | a=3
echo $a | echo $a
```

Perhaps that clarifies for you what is happening.  It would be surprising if you were able to change the variable in the top level shell by doing:

```
{ a=2; echo $a; } | { a=3; echo $a; } | echo $a
```

which provides the semantics that I believe you think your command is doing.

Comment: Yes, you got exactly what  it was confusing me as I realised after your first answer in the comment that I did not group my commands, I only created 2 pipes as I didn t use curly braces (which would have been truly surprising to modify my parent shell, exactly like you said). I feel ashamed that I didn't notice from the very beggining. Thank you again.